# Did I applied bootstrap 3 grid system right?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, multiple-columns, grid-system

Here is the initial markup:

```
<div class="product-related-products">
<div class="product-fields-title-wrapper"><span class="product-fields-title"><strong>Related products</strong></span>

</div>
<div class="product-field product-field-type-R">product1</div>
<div class="product-field product-field-type-R">product2</div>
<div class="product-field product-field-type-R">product3</div>
<div class="product-field product-field-type-R">product4</div>
<div class="product-field product-field-type-R">product5
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

I need to put these div.product-field.product-field-type-R into bootstrap 3 grid system with 4 columns at screens bigger then extrasmall screens
Here is my final markup:

```
<div class="product-related-products">
<div class="row product-fields-title-wrapper"><span class="product-fields-title"><strong>Related products</strong></span>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 product-field product-field-type-R">product1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 product-field product-field-type-R">product2</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 product-field product-field-type-R">product3</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 product-field product-field-type-R">product4</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 product-field product-field-type-R">product5</div>
</div>
```

Did I applied bootstrap 3 grid system right?

Comment: You've typed the classes correctly, yes.

Comment: thank you @lee. Here is the real usage of that code - http://antilopagold.su.xsph.ru/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=productdetails&virtuemart_product_id=4827&virtuemart_category_id=1id=0 It looks like it works, but why the first row of related products(this section is called "Похожие") is placed into 3 columns instead of 4?

Comment: Sorry, no idea what I'm looking at. If it's the icons, they look perfect. Have added an answer just in case it helps your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you have applied the grid classes correctly.

By what you have applied, the divs will be half width when displayed on a mobile device, and then quarter width when displayed on anything larger.